# The conquest movie with time manipulating machine that speeds up aging process?

Tags: story-identification, movie

So, not a time travel movie. It is set in a medieval-like world, with an evil witch stealing the time machine from the sorcerer, then she turns it up, causing everyone in the kingdom to get older very fast, so the quest is on to get the machine before everyone dies from aging.
If anyone knows what this movie is, it will be a miracle, Iäve been searching the web for this movie I once saw on TV for ages.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[To the Ends of Time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117929/)", a low-budget made-for-tv film from 1986.

The film's review in [Variety](http://variety.com/1996/film/reviews/to-the-ends-of-time-1200447967/) ticks all the right boxes:

> Set in a fantasy world where sailing ships fly and benevolent rulers
>   protect their kingdoms with strange weaponry, “To the Ends of Time” is
>   a fairy tale about the clash between time, humans’ greatest enemy, and
>   their most potent force, love.

...

> Tired of watching “pain, death and destruction,” the monarch is
>   determined to end war forever, calling upon the magical powers of his
>   alchemist, Aeschylus (Michael Silverback), to find the right solution.
>   After many sleepless nights, Aeschylus presents a most original
>   device: time. Whoever controls time, he reasons, will be the master of
>   the universe. With this powerful device, the victor can watch his
>   enemies age and die before their time. Before long, every human in the
>   world is aging at the alarming rate of one year per week, a giant
>   clock ticking away relentlessly inside an extinct volcano.
>
> Following the format and archetypes of fairy tales, yarn’s witch is a
>   black-haired sorceress named Karnissa (Sarah Douglas) who kills
>   Aeschylus, steals his plans and orders her followers to build the
>   monstrous device he’d invented.

Comment: That is the one!
THANKS!!!